# In MSTest how to check if last test passed (in TestCleanup)

Tags: selenium, mstest, webdriver

I'm creating web tests in Selenium using MSTest and want to take a screenshot everytime a test fails but I don't want to take one every time a test passes.

What I wanted to do is put a screenshot function inside the `[TestCleanup]` method and run it if test failed but not if test passed. But how do I figure out if a last test passed?

Currently I'm doing `bool = false` on `[TestInitialize]` and `bool = true` if test runs through.

But I don't think that's a very good solution.

So basically I'm looking for a way to detect if last test true/false when doing `[TestCleanup]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer by @MartinMussmann is correct, but incomplete. To access the ["TestContext" object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.currenttestoutcome%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you need to make sure to declare it as a property in your TestClass:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseTest
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

This is also mentioned in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209868/2912011).

Comment: That's right, but the code snippet gave me an error "TestContext must be of type TestContext, must be non-static, public and must not be read-only". So I changed the property to:

 `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }`

Comment: @LambdaCruiser Correct, I've update the answer with that suggestion

Answer (score 11):

Solution

```
if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
{
    // some code
}
```