# How to get test result status from MSTest?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

In NUnit, I can get the test result from `context.Result.State`. If its `NUnit.Framework.TestState.Success`, then I know the test passed.

In MSTest, how do I get that info?

I saw `context.Properties.Keys`, but none of them speak of the status of the test result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.currenttestoutcome%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property in the `TestCleanup` method:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    private TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed)
            //do something
    } 

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell how I can Get the actual reason/Log (means why my test case failed and on which Line Number) in the TestCleanup method ?

Comment: I have 3 test cases. How `TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed` will work in testcleanup() for the 3 test cases? Like how can I get result of all 3 three testcases?

Comment: When i tried this, having TestContext as a private property prevented the test from running at all. When public all is good

Comment: Just a note that with the `NUnit` test framework, `TestContext` is a static member of `NUnit.TestFramework` and does not need to be defined separately. With `MSTest` it must be defined `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }` as in the answer.