# Execute some code after a successful SQL Unit Test

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, unit-testing, stored-procedures

We have an application that has many SPROCs being developed and maintained by multiple developers, and we are trying to automate the process to keep track of modifying and testing the SPROCs. We currently have a table in our database that is populated and modified based on a trigger that fires when a SPROC is created, modified, or deleted. In this table there is a column that specifies whether the SPROC was tested and deemed a success by a unit test. We are using Visual Studio's Test Explorer and Unit Test designer to handle the SQL Unit tests. We have them functioning fine, but are trying to add automate to update the database after a test succeeds. Is there some kind of event or something similar that is touched by every successful unit test? If not, then at least something that can catch the results and allow some kind of additional logic after a(n) (un)successful execution?

Within the TestMethod itself, one of the objects returned is the SqlExecutionResult[] testResults object. Within this object is the hasError attribute, that when successful is set to true. It seems testResults isn't populated on some errors and is only ever null. Is there some method or something similar called by ALL unit tests upon completion that might be able to look back/use testResults to get confirmation of success? Something that can be used and catch the output from all unit tests?

Comment: Hi Rws10, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the results using a couple of slightly adjacent posts.

It comes down to creating a base test class that only has the `TestCleanup()` method and referencing the `TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome`.

You will then have the other test classes reference this as a base class and remove the reference to `TestCleanup()` in all of the other tests. This will allow for any kind of extra work to be done based on a success or failure of a unit test. To avoid this extra work, you could probably create a template using the base class. However, at this time we are not putting in the effort to figure this out since it's not a necessity.

These are the posts we referenced:

[How to get test result status from MSTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201566/how-to-get-test-result-status-from-mstest/13209868#13209868)

[In MSTest how to check if last test passed (in TestCleanup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253728/in-mstest-how-to-check-if-last-test-passed-in-testcleanup)

Answer (score 0):

This is something for all tests executed, not specifically passing tests only. You can create a stored procedure to reset and update that testing table/db as you need, and then use the `[SetUp]` method to ensure it triggers before every test is executed

As a basic example, using nUnit I have done

```cs
        private IMyRepo _repo;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            _repo = new MyRepoImpl();

            //reset db to a known state for each test
            using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(Settings.GetConnString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
                {
                    Connection = c,
                    CommandText = "DbReset",
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };

                c.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

You can setup the `DbReset` stored procedure used here to update that specific column

But a major caveat here is that this will fire before *every* test, not just successful or failed ones, and I'm not sure if there is such a specialization for a something to trigger for only passed tests.

In nUnit, `[TearDown]` methods are guaranteed to fire assuming the `[SetUp]` method did not throw an exception so you will have the same issue here. If there was a scenario where `[TearDown]`'s don't fire if the test fails, that could've been a hacky approach to solve your problem, but these types of methods are typically aimed at object creation and cleanup, so I highly doubt there is another testing suite that will attempt to do this (as, even in a failed test, the developer would still want cleanup to take place)

Sorry I can't provide the fix to the exact scenario you have, but I hope this gets you closer to your answer

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for.  I've added some detail for my post to clarify. My biggest concern is executing some kind of logic after a successful test. Specifically after.

Comment: @Rws10 Maybe broadening the search may turn up more ideas. For ex. This may be better handled with SQL than with C#: possibly look into [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which can be made to fire after an update is made to the table

Comment: We already have several triggers firing on the SQL side recording changes to the SPROCs themselves. We're trying to capture the results of the unit tests themselves, which are created and being run on the C# side of things using Visual Studio's Test Explorer. We found the solution in a slightly adjacent post, so I'll add the answer using that.